# Switch views depending on task result with swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios8, xcode6

I'm using NSURLSession to make a request to a server. To do this, I create a NSURLSessionTask with a custom completionHandler.

Depending on the result I want to switch to another view. However, when I do this inside the completion handler, it doesn't work. The app crashes with the following error:

```
NSInternalInconsistencyException
```

The full error is described by this:

```
*** Assertion failure in -[UIKeyboardTaskQueue waitUntilAllTasksAreFinished], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3302.3.1/Keyboard/UIKeyboardTaskQueue.m:374

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIKeyboardTaskQueue waitUntilAllTasksAreFinished] may only be called from the main thread.'
```

Note: to change views I use the following code

```
let vc: AnyObject! = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(viewID)
self.showViewController(vc as UIViewController, sender: vc)
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: @Rob I've now added the error. Also, I tried to follow your advice and it didn't work.

Comment: I've used it already, it makes no difference. But just to be sure, that is supposed to be on my completion handler, right?

Comment: Oh wait! My mistake. I was calling the showViewController before the dispatch method, and inside the dispatch method too! I deleted the first, it's all fine now! thank you @rob

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The main issue is that your error message is reporting that "... may only be called from the main thread". So you presumably have invoked this code from within a background thread (perhaps a completion block for network request or something like that). So you have to dispatch this code back to the main queue:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    let vc = self.storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(viewID) as UIViewController
    showViewController(vc, sender: self)
}
```

Note, this code snippet makes a few minor, unrelated changes, namely:

1. It doesn't make sense to specify the destination view controller as its own sender. Usually you'd use the current view controller or some UIKit control as the `sender`.

   I specified `self` as the `sender`, because I presume you did this in the source view controller. Or, if this was in an `IBAction` for a button, maybe you'd use the `sender` parameter of the `IBAction`, itself, instead of the source view controller.
2. I would lose the `AnyObject` cast. I know the compiler probably suggested it to you, but it doesn't help the legibility of the code. I'd suggest directly casting it to a `UIViewController`.

Answer (score 1):

Anything you do that affects the user interface has to be run on the main thread, not in a completion handler.  So inside your completion handler, call performSelectorOnMainThread or use one of the other mechanisms that allow you to put that call onto the main thread.

Comment: can you give an example using that function? xcode does not compile in every way I tried it.